# Implement a Repository Interface into Job

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I am trying to implement an Interface into a Job but having no luck. Is it possible to implement an interface / repository within the public construct and use said interface in the `handle()` method of the Job?

The error I am getting is as follows:

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Jobs\OrderCreate::__construct() must be an instance of App\Http\Interfaces\OrderInterface, string given, called in /Users/Panoply/Sites/stock-sync/app/Http/Controllers/StockController.php on line 31
```

Below is a basic setup of what I am trying to achieve.

Stock Controller:

```
public function test(){
   dispatch(new OrderCreate('hello'));
}
```

OrderCreate Job:

```
protected $order;
protected $test;

public function __construct(OrderInterface $order, $test)
{
    $this->order = $order;
    $this->test = $test;
}

public function handle()
{
    $this->order->test($this->test);
}
```

OrderRepository:

```
class OrderRepository implements OrderInterface
{
    public function test($data) {
        error_log($data);
    }
}
```

OrderInterface:

```
public function test($data);
```

I have had no troubles implementing this pattern into my controllers and commands but I can't seem to get it working on a Job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, the issue was I shouldn't of been calling the interface within the `__construct()` but instead within `handle()`

**Editing for more detailed explanation.**

The `__construct()` of a Laravel / Lumen Job from what I can tell only accepts data and thus implementing an interface within the `__constuct()` will cause my above error to be thrown.

In order to use an Interface within a job, you will need to call your interface within the `handle()` function.

As an example, the following will **NOT** work within a Job class:

```
protected $test;

public function __construct(InterfaceTest $test)
{
     $this->test = $test;
}
```

This is because the Job construct does not take in Interfaces, it only takes in the data you pass in from the `dispatch` call. In order to use your Interface within a job, you need to call the interface within the `handle()` function and then it will succeed and work, example:

```
public function handle(InterfaceTest $test)
{
     $test->fn();
}
```

This seems to only be the case when implementing on a Job. In most cases when you require an interface within a Controller or Command, you will implement within the `__construct()`.

Comment: Please share your solution, it could help others. Thank you!!

Comment: @SachinVairagi gave a more solution for anyone that might come across this issue.